# How to use medialibrary in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I use medialibrary in Laravel and when I run tests, show me error `Class "Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media" not found`. Someone know how I get this error ?

Comment: update for the right model in your config file `config/medialibrary.php`

Answer (score 0):

First check if package is install or not
if not install then
run this for installing package

```
composer require "spatie/laravel-medialibrary
```

Then Publish The vendor for spatie media library

```
 php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"
```

then run migrate command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: "_I use medialibrary in Laravel and when I run tests_" sounds like OP is already using it, just tests throw that error